# When I try to debug the project all the test auto run. How I stop this

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I debug the project for viewing and fixing design issue than I see all the test are running as well. How I stop this so that my tests don't run while working on my UI project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Testing project (or any project for that matter) in your solution and you don't want it to start up, right-click on your solution in Solution Explorer and choose Properties. Click on
Common Properties->Startup Project. You'll probably see "Multiple startup projects" selected. If you choose "None" in the drop-down in the Action column for your test project(s), this should stop them from starting up when you debug your solution.

This is for VS2008 but 2005 and 2010 should be similar.

Comment: Just checked. All are None and only single startup project radio button is checked still than Test project is running.

Comment: Try going to Build->Configuration Manager and unchecking the Build box for the Test project.